# Why is my GeoJSON object being rejected by LeafletKNN?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using [Leaflet KNN](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-knn) to find points nearest to an index layer. I'm getting a super strange result that I can't explain. I pass in a valid GeoJSON object, but Leaflet KNN continually rejects it.

I'm using Leaflet v1.5.1 and LeafletKNN v0.1.0.

```js
const geo = L.geoJSON(this.data); <-- validated GeoJSON using GeoJSONlint.com
console.log(geo instanceof L.GeoJSON); // TRUE
this.index = leafletKnn(geo); // Uncaught Error: must be L.GeoJSON
```

Here's the line in LeafletKNN that is throwing the error -- it's the same test I'm running that passes before I pass it in to LeafletKNN.

```js
module.exports = function(layer) {
  if (!(layer instanceof L.GeoJSON)) throw new Error('must be L.GeoJSON');
  ...
```

I posted a [demo of the app](https://www.fws.gov/southeast/test/) with the un-babelified bundle, which runs in Chrome. To experience the error choose the 'Zipcode' option and type in a valid five digit zipcode; errors appear in the console.

I've tried removing the node_modules folder and reinstalling everything, reinstalling leafletknn, and verified my GeoJSON is valid using geojsonlint.com.

### Data sample

```js
[
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 1,
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -162.201641272281,
        6.14299987296321
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "OBJECTID": 1,
      "FWSRegion": "1",
      "CCCode": "FF01RKGM00",
      "POINT_X": -162.201626208,
      "POINT_Y": 6.142995245,
      "OrgCode": 12534,
      "OrgName": "Kingman Reef National Wildlife Refuge",
      "OrgType": "NWR",
      "UrlFishing": " ",
      "DescFish": null,
      "State": "USMOI",
      "UrlStation": " ",
      "DescHunt": null,
      "YouthHuntFS": null,
      "UrlHunting": null,
      "BigGame": "no",
      "SmallGame": "no",
      "Waterfowl": "no",
      "MigratoryBirds": "no",
      "UplandBirds": "no",
      "Turkey": "no",
      "Exotics": "no",
      "FishingOpen": "no",
      "FreshwaterFishing": "no",
      "TidalFishing": "no",
      "Shellfishing": "no",
      "PermitRequired": "no",
      "PermitOpportunities": null,
      "PermitRequirements": null,
      "PermitObtained": null,
      "State_Array": [
        null
      ],
      "State_Label": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 4,
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -95.9455165346589,
        48.3456214415358
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "OBJECTID": 4,
      "FWSRegion": "3",
      "CCCode": "FF03RAGS00",
      "POINT_X": -95.945507481,
      "POINT_Y": 48.345613195,
      "OrgCode": 32510,
      "OrgName": "Agassiz National Wildlife Refuge",
      "OrgType": "NWR",
      "UrlFishing": " ",
      "DescFish": null,
      "State": "MN",
      "UrlStation": "http://www.fws.gov/refuge/agassiz/",
      "DescHunt": "The forests and wetlands of this northwestern Minnesota refuge are known by outdoors enthusiasts across the nation as one of the continent's best wildlife watching areas. Each year, thousands of waterfowl nest here, including giant Canada goose, canvasback and ruddy duck. Wolves and moose roam the forests. Hunters can enjoy this \"wildlife wonderland\" while pursuing white-tailed deer on the refuge. While the northern forests don't have the deer densities found in many parts of the country, Agassiz NWR does offer a real adventure for hunters who want to get away from the crowds. Successful hunters often use portable stands along deer trails, and some use bicycles (permitted on refuge trails) to reach more inaccessible areas. A 4,000-acre wilderness area allows only walk-in hunting for those who want to explore the refuge's wild backcountry. An annual youth waterfowl hunt is held on the Farmers Pool Unit of the refuge.",
      "YouthHuntFS": "A youth waterfowl hunt is held.",
      "UrlHunting": "https://www.fws.gov/refuge/Agassiz/visit/visitor_activities.html",
      "BigGame": "yes",
      "SmallGame": "no",
      "Waterfowl": "yes",
      "MigratoryBirds": "yes",
      "UplandBirds": "yes",
      "Turkey": "no",
      "Exotics": "no",
      "FishingOpen": "no",
      "FreshwaterFishing": "no",
      "TidalFishing": "no",
      "Shellfishing": "no",
      "PermitRequired": "no",
      "PermitOpportunities": null,
      "PermitRequirements": null,
      "PermitObtained": null,
      "State_Array": [
        "Minnesota"
      ],
      "State_Label": "Minnesota"
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

A third-party package, [esri-leaflet-related](https://github.com/jgravois/esri-leaflet-related) was somehow causing this error. When I removed the package and implemented the REST API calls for related records myself the error disappeared.

Bonus: my bundle size was reduced by ~200kb.